# pandas Series.replace() not generating default value from defaultdict

Tags: python, pandas, replace, collections, defaultdict

I could always .fillna() after. But I'm trying to implement a value for "OTHER" as part of the recoding-dict. I thought a defaultdict might be a good fit, but it seems to behave like a generator, and pandas Series.replace() does not seem to generate results for keys not requested earlier in the code.

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

recode = defaultdict(lambda:"Unknown", {
    1 : "Yes",
    2 : "No"
})

print("key 0:", recode[0]) # Will generate a key-value for the key "0"

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([0,1,2,5]), columns = ["code"])
df['answer'] = df['code'].replace(recode)
print(df)
```

Will generate this output:

```
key 0: Unknown
   code   answer
0     0  Unknown
1     1      Yes
2     2       No
3     5        5
```

So since we called print() on recode[0] this gets generated, and can be used by pd.Series.replace(), but recode[5] is ONLY searched for by pd.Series.replace() and is therefore not replaced by "Unknown" like I expected.

Suggestions? (on how to include an "OTHER" within the recode-datastructure)

**Accepted Answer**

Building on [Anurag Dabas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14289892/anurag-dabas)s answer, you can just use map...

```
recode = defaultdict(lambda:"Unknown", {
    1 : "Yes",
    2 : "No",
    None: "Ah shit"
})
df['answer'] = df['code'].map(recode)
```

Output:

```
    code    answer
0   0   Unknown
1   1   Yes
2   2   No
3   5   Unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
print("key 0:", recode[0])
```

Since there is no key 0 exist in record so it will generate a key 0 with value 'Unknown' because you are not assigning any value while creating a 0 key in the defaultdict

so now recode becomes:

```
print(record)
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>()>, {1: 'Yes', 2: 'No', 0: 'Unknown'})
```

so Now if you do:

```
df['answer'] = df['code'].replace(recode)
```

0 is replaced with 'Unknown' because there exist a value of 0 inside the defaultdict recode i.e 'Unknown' and there is no value of 5 exist in the default dict so it remained unchanged and you can checked that by:

```
print('keys: ',recode.keys(),'\nvalues: ',recode.values())

keys:  dict_keys([1, 2, 0]) 
values:  dict_values(['Yes', 'No', 'Unknown'])
```

**Update:**

you can use simple dictionary or defaultdict with `map()`+`fillna()`:

```
df['answer'] = df['code'].map({1:'Yes',2:'No'}).fillna('Other')
```

output of `df`:

```
    code    answer
0   0       Other
1   1       Yes
2   2       No
3   5       Other
```

Comment: Yes, do you have an alternative suggestion for a data-type I could switch to that would allow for the replace-function to receive a value for "other" from the dict-like-data?

Comment: @CarlF.Corneil so sir you want answer column values like this `['other','yes','no','other']`?

Comment: @CarlF.Corneil updated answer....kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: ah, nice. Yes, this could work with defaultdict as well, by referencing a key directly that should not exist in the defaultdict.
df['answer'] = df['code'].map(recode).fillna(recode[None])

Comment: @CarlF.Corneil but `df['code'].map(recode).fillna(recode[None])` will create additional entries in the defaultdict for each value that are 'Unknown'

Comment: I think maybe Im getting the desired result with a pure .map without the .fillna
Like you say, the map function creates new entries in the defaultdict, but that is fine. Its more important for me that the defaultdict can enter the code correctly, than it being saved after usage.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the pandas.core _replace_columnwise [checks if the keys are in the mapping before replacing](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e045034e5c89b932a526d6c9e691d3031784c377/pandas/core/frame.py#L5248).

So after the example code above is run, you can check which will be replaced or not with the logic.

```
print(0 in recode)
print(5 in recode)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

So i guess this is something to ask the pandas developers, if they can support dict-like generators in the replace-function?